# FFmpeg concat produces bad Video

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, containers, concatenation

I have installed ffmpeg on a microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime docker container using 
1.apt-get update
2.apt-get install ffmpeg.

seems to be installed fine, but when I try and use it as such
ffmpeg -f concat -i /data/mylist.txt -c: copy /data/output.mp4

the output is that the first video part is ok, but the second colors are all messy (hard to explain) and when I change the order of the videos in the list still the first in the list is ok and the second is messed up.

p.s same settings on a different machine works (ffmpeg for ubuntu)

bad

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ccbcce90c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from '/data/mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14915 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14915 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-17T04:06:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
Output #0, mp4, to '/data/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 14915 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-17T04:06:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
```

good

```
Input #0, concat, from '/data/mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14915 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14915 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-17T04:06:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
Output #0, mp4, to '/data/outGood1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 14915 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-17T04:06:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
```

Comment: The first is ffmpeg 3.2 and the other is 4.1.1 (latest release). Upgrade ffmpeg in the container. The latest version might not be available in the default repositories.

Comment: So i will have to build it from the source on the container?

Comment: or find a repo, package or static build. Check out https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Next time please avoid [crossposting the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1411745/ffmpeg-concat-produces-bad-video) on multiple Stack Exchange sites. It dilutes effort and wastes time.